js watchmen activate the node command on a file
I'm trying to use: https://github.com/facebook/watchman
But it's not working, I need to make sure that when a file called test2.js that is in the current path is modified then the node test2.js command is executed again.
I tried like this:
watchman -- trigger . jsfiles '**/*.js' -- node test2.js

Quello che ottengo è questo:
{
    "version": "2024.05.06.00",
    "disposition": "created",
    "triggerid": "jsfiles"
}

How do I make the command run every time the file is modified, what am I doing wrong?
